# Como funcionam as anotações em Java?

Tags: java, ejb, annotation

Gostaria de saber como são feitas as anotações EJB em Java, aquelas que começam com "@"

Comment: Já deu uma olhada na [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/index.html)? especialmente na seção sobre [declaração de anotações](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/declaring.html)

Comment: Obrigado amigo!!